# Firebase database schema

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I can't understand the way Firebase db works.
Yes, I know it is a JSON with my data, I know the ways to set one-to-many and many-to-many relationship between different objects. But is there any way to set up some kind of "*schema*" to database?

An example to understand what I mean: what if I'm creating an Android app, using Firebase SDK, and my friend is creating an iOS app. I'm pushing this to `"users": {name: John, city: LA}`. And my friend makes a mistake, pushing `{name: Tom, cety: NY}`. Than, trying to get Toms city - what will I get? Null?

Is there a way to specify a structure to saved data. In Firebase console I see only way to add exact values, not specify the way it should be structured. How to tell other developers, or "*me-in-the-future*" that my users should contain, for example "name", "gender" and "dog_eyes_color"?
Hope you understand me.

Comment: You can validate the data structure on the Firebase servers using so-called security rules. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data and then specifically the `.validate` rules in there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that ".validate" rule looks exactly what I need.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen one more thing. You say when authorizing user for the first time - firebase creates needed record in database. Is there some kind of reserved "users" node under root in database? If so - how can I specify that the id of users there is  for example their username, or email. And what if I want to create a new recor in database only if user provided some valuable data. Example: dating app. register user only when it has specified gender, city and who he is looking for.

Comment: Firebase does not auto-create a record in the database for a user (let me know from where you got that idea and I'll get it updated). To create such a record, you will have to write code. Which also means you control exactly when the record is created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question, Firebase is a schema-less database. If you push data to a node

```
users
  uid_0
    name: John
    city: LA
```

and your friend adds another user

```
  uid_1
    name: Frank
    cety: NY
```

Then your users node will have two users with children that have different keys; city vs cety.

As Frank mentioned in his comment, you can 'catch' and prevent data from being written to a node that's invalid. However, ponder this class:

```
class User {
   userId = ""
   name = ""
   city = ""

   func saveToFirebase() {
      myRef.setValue( user id etc etc)
   }
}
```

and you tell your friend that any time they want to store a user in Firebase, to use that class. You now have a standardized model in which to interact with Firebase. That class (or structure or whatever you use) defines a schema to work with.

> The Firebase database (NoSQL) provides a mechanism for storage and retrieval
>   of data which is modeled in means other than the tabular relations
>   used in relational databases

And as a followup to the users question: Firebase DOES store user authentication data 'in the back end' which is not directly accessible (queryable) to the developer. The idea here is that when a user is created in Firebase with Firebase functions such as createUser(), you are provided the user id (UID) of that user when it's created and that's what you can use to store additional information in a /users node you create.

```
users
   uid_0
    name: Frank
    location: LA
    fav_food: Pizza
   uid_1
    name: Leroy
    location: NY
    fav_food: Tacos
```

.validate....
I would not leverage .validate rules to define a structure (schema) or keep other developers in check. Providing coding tools such as the Users class mentioned above will provide far more flexibility and less aggravation (and coding) in the long run and will be much more maintainable.

Comment: you have mentioned a point that 
*. You now have a standardized model in which to interact with Firebase. That class (or structure or whatever you use) defines a schema to work with.*

But can you share a link , to create and define a shcema with a class defined, I dont see any such link. if possible, please give the link ,which has flask and firebase schemas docs.

Comment: @RohanDevaki I may be able to help but I am not sure I understand your question. You ask *can you share a link , to create and define a shcema* but my question says *Firebase is a schema-less database* so there is no schema. The Class in your code provides the structure for your data. If you're using Firestore you can populate Class objects directly as shown in this example from the docs [Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects)

Answer (score 1):

how about this way of implementation

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, city) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    return {
      name: this.name,
      city: this.city,
    };
  }
}

const saveDocument = function (collectionName, obj) {
  db.collection(collectionName)
    .add(obj)
    .then((docRef) => {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
};



saveDocument("user", new User("Jhon", "NY"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following answer goes for anyone using Firestore and having this same question.

Firebase security rules, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw) does an amazing job explaining them, are a way in which you can sort of create schemas.

An important consideration when using these rules is that if you're using the [Firestore Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) (used for backend code) then your rules will be bypassed. To enforce this rules the request must come from a [client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). I think that one of the best things about Firebase is [serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) so this type of validations should work just fine with most requests considering they come from the client.

To validate requests coming from a source that bypasses the basic security rules make sure to set up [Identity and Access Management (IAM) for Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam).

Comment: I was making SSR with next.js and Firestore Firebase Admin . I stored firebase Id token as cookie . And I can't add security rules .  So rules are bypass or not  in my SSR app?

Comment: If the SSR app in question is utilizing the Firestore Firebase Admin SDK for interactions with Firebase, the Firebase security rules will be bypassed. On the other hand, if client SDKs are used for these interactions (even in an SSR setup), the security rules will be enforced.